# cat-file tag object report fatal

Tags: git

I have created a object tag

```
git tag -a tag_1 -m "test tag"
```

But the following command reports a fatal error:

```
git cat-file -t tag_1^{tag}
fatal: Not a valid object name tag_1^{tag}
```

However, the following one works fine:

```
git cat-file -t master^{commit}
commit
```

Why does it report fatal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax used to specify an object in [`git cat-file`](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-cat-file.html) is the one specified in [gitrevisions](http://schacon.github.com/git/gitrevisions.html).

```
<object>
```

> The name of the object to show.
>   For a more complete list of ways to spell object names, see the "`SPECIFYING REVISIONS`" section in gitrevisions(7).

And it applies to a `<rev>`.

```
<rev>^{<type>}, e.g. v0.99.8^{commit}
```

> A suffix `^` followed by an object type name enclosed in brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until an object of that type is found or the object cannot be dereferenced anymore (in which case, barf).
>   `<rev>^0` is a short-hand for `<rev>^{commit}`.

In this case, I am not sure it can dereference `tag_1` "until an object of that type is found" (since it is already a tag).

Comment: <type> include tree blob commit tag.

following is catched from gitrevisions(7)

<rev>^{<type>}, e.g. v0.99.8^{commit}

A suffix ^ followed by an object type name enclosed in brace pair means the object could be a tag, and dereference the tag recursively until an object of that type is found or the object cannot be dereferenced anymore (in which case, barf). <rev>^0 is a short-hand for <rev>^{commit}.

Comment: @Vince "`<type>` include tree blob commit tag". Agreed. "`v0.99.8^{commit}`" means dereference the tag `v0.99.8` until you find a commit. But in your case, you try to dereference a tag until you find a tag. Which I am not sure ti could (should) work.

Comment: the orginal one says:"dereference the tag recursively until an object of that type is found". note the keywork "that type". So I think it should return self if the target type is tag. Maybe it's by design(as an exception) or fixed in future. :)